# NSTimer is pausing a while when UIGesture action performed

Tags: objective-c, ios

NSTimer is pausing a while an then again it is starting when UIGesture action performed.

I am developing an iOS application where I have to trigger the NSTimer repeatedly for every 0.5 seconds and based on that timer I'm moving a song progress bar. And also handling touch events when user touching on some images which I kept on the same view. I am seeing when user touches the images, the timer for moving the progress bar is stopping a little while and continues again.

Are there any problem that we can't handle timer and touch events at the same time in the same view?

My code for timer

```
myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timeinterval target:self selector:@selector(updatplayer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:myTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common issue with NSTimer. While you can play with run loop modes to improve things, a nicer solution is to switch to GCD timers. See [RNTimer](https://github.com/rnapier/RNTimer) for an example. See the docs on [dispatch_source_create](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/GCDWorkQueues/GCDWorkQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH103-SW1) for more information.

Comment: With NSTimer we cannot handle this one?

Comment: It's generally more trouble than it's worth to fight with NSTimer's run loop modes since GCD tends to do it all much more easily and without creating retain loops. But in your code you're scheduling yourself twice and that might be causing the problem. Don't use the "scheduled" variant if you're going to call addTimer yourself. That's scheduling twice.